# Sliding cross-correlation

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, clustering, similarity

I want to understand Timeseries shape similarity algorithm ( Shape-based distance aka SBD). I can't understand the statistics behind it and why it is better than DTW or other similarity measure. I'm trying to read this paper http://www1.cs.columbia.edu/~jopa/Papers/PaparrizosSIGMOD2015.pdf but can't understand anything in this regard. Any explanation with some example is really appreciated.

I started with learning about cross-correlation, normalized cross-correlation, Auto-Correlation, Normalization and Time Shift.

https://anomaly.io/understand-auto-cross-correlation-normalized-shift/

I couldn't understand the concept of sliding cross-correlation which is used to identify shape based similarity. What is "sliding" in this type of correlation and what difference it's making?

Comment: Welcome to data science. You need to focus your questions. It isn't likely that someone will read the entire article for you and sum it up. Ask specific questions.

Comment: @Mark.F is it possible to answer now?